# Add text to each column

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, sed

I have the following lines

```
3, 3, 100
4, 2, 50
8, 5, 80
.
.
.
```

and I want the following output

```
line starts at 3 and ends at 3 with value 100
line starts at 4 and ends at 2 with value 50
line starts at 8 and ends at 5 with value 80
.
.
.
```

I tried the following: `sed 's/^/line starts at /'` then applying this command for the output: `sed 's/, / and ends at /'` then applying this command for the output `sed 's/, / with value /'`. Is there any way to do it in a single line?

Comment: I tried the following: sed 's/^/line starts at /' then applying this command for the output: sed 's/, / and ends at /' then applying this command for the output sed 's/, / with value /'. Is there any way to do it in a single line?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`awk` is good for this kind of formatted input - formatted output:

```
awk -F, '{printf("line starts at %d and ends at %d with value %d\n", $1, $2, $3)}' file 
line starts at 3 and ends at 3 with value 100
line starts at 4 and ends at 2 with value 50
line starts at 8 and ends at 5 with value 80
```

Comment: This is absolutely beautiful!

Answer (score 3):

A shell `while read` loop with `printf`:

```
while IFS=', ' read c1 c2 c3; do
    printf 'line starts at %s and ends at %s with value %s\n' \
        "$c1" "$c2" "$c3"
done <file
```

By setting the `IFS` variable to a space and a comma, the `read` command will use those characters as field delimiters.

Output:

```
line starts at 3 and ends at 3 with value 100
line starts at 4 and ends at 2 with value 50
line starts at 8 and ends at 5 with value 80
```

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that there is -e option in sed

```
sed -e 's/^/line starts at /g' -e 's/, / and ends at /' -e 's/, / with value at /'
```

Comment: see also: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Multiple-commands-syntax

Comment: @Franky, steeldriver has better answer

Comment: @WashichawbachaW I do agree! It is a much better line

Answer (score 0):

There is a easy and fast way to do this in shell itself:-

```
# cat f
3, 3, 100
4, 2, 50
8, 5, 80

# cat f | while read line ;  do  IFS=", " array=($line) ; echo "line starts at ${array[0]} and ends at ${array[1]} with value ${array[2]}"; done 

line starts at 3 and ends at 3 with value 100
line starts at 4 and ends at 2 with value 50
line starts at 8 and ends at 5 with value 80
```

Comment: Why not split it up in the read itself instead of doing the extra step of creating an array?

Comment: I hope you're not actually running this as root…

Comment: Oh yes, that is much better